Will my equations accurately calculate objects' drag coefficients?
Context: I am in highschool, writing an extended essay on different nose cone designs and reducing the coefficient of drag. I am performing an experiment myself to record data. A 3D printed object will be dropped from a known height and the time it takes for the object to reach the "ground" will be measured.
Question: does this mathematical process yield physically accurate results?
$h=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^{2}$
$a=\frac{2h}{t^{2}}$
$a_{average}=g-(F_{d})_{average}, v_{average}=\frac{h}{t}$
$(F_{d})_{average}=\frac{1}{2}pv_{average}^{2}(C_{d})_{average}A$
$(F_{d})_{average}=\frac{1}{2}p(\frac{h}{t})^{2}(C_{d})_{average}A$
$(g-(\frac{1}{2}p(\frac{h}{t})^{2}(C_{d})_{average}A))=\frac{2h}{t^{2}}$
$C_{d}=\frac{2\left(gt^{2}-2h\right)}{ph^{2}A}$

To start, your second equation is missing $h$

typo I have edited

The equation you're using for $h$ is only true if you assume $a$ is constant, but it's not.
Your should be starting from an equation like this (which involves calculus):
$$F_{net}=F_{gravity}-F_{drag}$$
That becomes a differential equation:
$$m\frac{dv}{dt}=mg-F_{drag}$$
Drag is typically modeled as being proportional to velocity raised to some power and if you've done high school math that might be a bit advanced for you.
You should read Wikipedia's page on drag to get a better idea on the mathematics.
Now this does not mean your approach won't yield useful results, but you are starting our from a false assumption (net acceleration being constant).  That said even the models I have described are only approximations.  Real drag calculations can become surprisingly complex for real objects.

I am performing an experiment myself to record data. A 3D printed object will be dropped from a known height and the time it takes for the object to reach the "ground" will be measured.

This is good.  Measurements in physics are always good.  Physics without measurements is just playing with mathematics.
The lighter and larger your object the better to measure these effects.  Something light, maybe a hollow shape of thin plastic.  Remember that the gravitational acceleration is constant, but the drag depends on area and is divided by the mass.  A moderately light object with a good cross sectional area would show more effect.  At one extreme you have e.g. a feather or a piece of paper.  That's too light.  It's worth experimenting to see what gives you clear evidence of drag.

Thanks I am aware of my assumption about the acceleration, that is what has been causing me the most skepticism with my method. Can this method still yield a result for an average drag coefficient? Assuming the Cd remains constant, which it theoretically should at high Reynolds number? If not I will pursue the calculus approach :)
